# service to use to host a app built using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting

What service should I use to host an app that I am building using ruby on rails. It would be a big plus if it could connect to Github and let you use your own domain name easily.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of options to choose from. Two of the most popular (and best supported, in my opinion) are Heroku and EngineYard.

Here are articles for each on how to use your own domain name with them:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains
https://support.cloud.engineyard.com/entries/21016458-Set-up-Domains-and-DNS

As far as linking to Github, each can be setup as a remote location for git, making deployment easy. Also, if you really want to allow to directly link you can find a how-to for EngineYard if you go to their site and search for "Link a GitHub Account to an Engine Yard Cloud Account" (I can't post the link because I don't have enough reputation points here yet to post more than two links).